# How to extend the datepicker widget to create a new datetimepicker widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I would like to achieve the following implementation:

I want to use the jQuery UI datepicker combined with another jQuery UI widget.

That is, I would like to create a new widget which somehow calls the jquery UI datepicker widget and allows me to create more elements on the bottom of the widget (combining two widgets together as the datepicker shows on the top and my own widget shows on the bottom).

Notice that I don't need any option of the jQuery UI datepicker itself but a new widget combined of the jQuery UI datepicker with another widget which on init calls the datepicker somehow.

Is there a way to achieve it ?

The reason why I need it is to create a new widget where the datepicker is on top and my own timepicker is below constitute a new widget called datetimepicker (I know there are some built-in widgets but I want to create my own).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not taking inspiration from here : https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/blob/master/src/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js ???

Answer (score 0):

You could better split the component in three part..

1. jQuery UI datepicker
2. Your own timepicker
3. Widget to combine both datepicker and timepicker

This way you could either use datepicker and timepicker togheter or separated.

I'll supose you already have a timepicker widget, and use it like this: `$("#timepicker").timepicker();`

Then, you will have another jQuery plugin to achieve the combination of the two other plugins.. For example:

```
<div id="datetimepicker"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.datetimepicker = function(){
    var datepicker = $('<div>').datepicker();
    var timepicker = $('<div>').timepicker();
    $(this).append(datepicker).append(timepicker);
}
$("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
</script>
```